# Fit a GEE-model of type "exchangeable" with gamm

Tags: r, spline, mgcv

I would like to estimate a smooth effect of some covariate `N` in a marginal model of type "exchangeable" in R, where the clustering variable is `S`. From what I could find, this should be possible with:

`geeglm(..., id = S, corstr = "exchangeable")`

as well as:

`gamm(..., correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~1|S))`

Below you can find an example where the results look good in a sense that the two estimates are quite close. However, if I use the real data our project is about, the estimated smooth effects tend to be very different. I cannot publish that here, but maybe someone can still spot some problem in the code. For instance (see below), the `gamm`-object says `Number of Groups: 1` which worries me as there clearly is more than one cluster...

(Yes, this is the realisation of a random-effects-model by construction, but this should lead to the desired model given the answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-compound-symmetry-in-plain-english/15107).)

```
########
## Packages
########
library(ggplot2)
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)
library(geepack)
library(splines)

########
## Data Simulation
########
f        <- function(N) {return((-200+(N-25)^2)/100)}

N        <- sort(sample(1:50, 10, replace = T))
S        <- as.character(1:10)
S_Effect <- rnorm(length(S),0,1)
S_Effect <- rep(S_Effect,N)
S        <- rep(S,N)
N        <- rep(N,N)
E        <- runif(length(N))

data     <- data.frame(O        = rep(0,length(N)),
                       E        = E,
                       N        = N,
                       S        = as.factor(S),
                       S_Effect = S_Effect)

for (i in 1:length(N)) {
  data$O[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, plogis(f(N[i]) + qlogis(E[i]) + S_Effect[i]))}

data <- data %>% mutate(E = qlogis(E))



########
## Fitting
########
formula_gamm   <- as.formula("O ~ 1 + offset(E) + s(N, bs = 'bs')")
model_gamm     <- gamm(formula_gamm, family = binomial(), correlation = corCompSymm(form=~1|S), data = data)
model_gamm

formula_geeglm <- as.formula("O ~ 1 + offset(E) + bs(N)")
model_geeglm   <- geeglm(formula_geeglm, family = binomial(), corstr = "exchangeable", id = S, data = data)



########
## Plot
########
pred_gamm      <- plot.gam(model_gamm$gam, select = 1)
x <- pred_gamm[[1]]$x
pred_geeglm  <- predict(model_geeglm, type = "terms", newdata = data.frame(E = rep(0,length(x)), N = x))

z                 <- qnorm(0.9)

tmp               <- data.frame(x = x,
                               y = pred_gamm[[1]]$fit,
                               group = rep("estimate gamm",length(x)))
tmp2               <- data.frame(x = x,
                                y = as.numeric(pred_geeglm),
                                group = rep("estimate geeglm",length(x)))
tmp3              <- data.frame(x = x,
                               y = f(x),
                               group = rep("actual function",length(x)))

data_pred = bind_rows(tmp,tmp2,tmp3) %>% mutate(group = as.factor(group))

p <- ggplot(data = data_pred, aes(x = x, y = y, color = group)) +
     geom_line(size = 2) +
     xlab("N") +
     ylab("f(N)")
p
```

An additional question: The `gamm`-object contains enough information to plot a confidence-band around the estimated function, but how can I do this for the `geeglm`-estimate? You get something that looks reasonable if you `simulate(model_geeglm, ...)` and take the pointwise `mean` and so on, but that doesn't really satisfy me as (1) the documentation on `simulate` doesn't mention marginal models and (2) it is very primitive...

Answer (score 0):

The GAMM is using penalised splines, such that the degrees of freedom used by the resulting spline (smoother) is likely to be somewhat less than the requested basis dimension, which is 10. The GEE is fitting an unpenalized model. All else equal, the unpenalised model will be more wiggly than the penalised one.

To compare these approaches on a common footing, you need to make sure that `bs()` and `s(x, bs = 'bs')` both produce the same number of basis functions (The `s()` version can produce one fewer as it will remove the lack identifiability with the intercept term, whereas you are omitting the intercept in the `bs()` version).

Having assured yourself that you get the same basis dimension, then you can make GAMM fit an unpenalized spline by adding `fx = TRUE` to the `s(...)` term in the formula.

Having done that, both models should be estimating similar smooth effects.

However, I would suggest that you use penalisation; For the GAMM model, use `fx = FALSE`, and then after estimating the model run `gam.check(model$gam)` (replacing `model` with your fitted model object) and see if the basis size check passes for the smoother.